# determine population size and confidence interval

Tags: statistics

In a private library the books are kept on 130 shelves of similar size. The number of books on 15 shelves picked at random were found to be 28,23,25,33,31,18,22,29,30,22,26,20,21,28 and 28 estimate the total number Y of books in the library and calculate 95 percentage confidence interval for Y.

Any help on what approach to take would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to interpret 'shelves of similar size' to mean something useful and assume that the data given are from a normal population. You also have to assume data were taken on a typical day. If it's a lending library, there might be times when more books are checked out than usual. The maximum book count in your list of 15 is 33. I'm wondering if we have to account for an absolute maximum capacity for these shelves---would that be about 35 or 40? If this were a question
from the real world and not a textbook exercise, we'd have to think about all sorts of possibilities. But for a textbook exercise, assuming normality seems safe.

Here is one possible approach:

First, find a 95% t confidence interval for the average number $\mu$ of books on a typical shelf.
That's $\bar X \pm 2.145 S/\sqrt{n},$ where 2.145 cuts probability 2.5% from
the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $\nu = n-1 = 14$ degrees of
freedom, $\bar X$ is the mean of your sample and $S$ is its standard deviation.

You should look for this formula in your book.
I got about $(25.6, 28.1)$ as a 95% confidence for $\mu.$ You should probably
refine that answer to show two or three place accuracy.

Second, multiply the endpoints by $130$ shelves because the average number of books in the library is $130\mu.$ I got about $(3330, 2450)$ as a confidence
interval for the number of books, an answer which you should verify by doing your own calculations.

---

*Note:* Assuming the book counts given as data are Poisson distributed, I got
about $(3330, 3660)$ as the confidence interval for the number of books
in the library.